# Hiding a image under the div

Tags: css, visibility

Take a look at this screenshoot first:

[image]

That white box is ON the orange background, I want it to be under it exactly as pointed with the arrow. The rest should be visible of course: it should just hide this from being on the orange background.

Here is the orange background style and the white box itself:

Orange background:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url("../img/back.png") repeat-x top #fff;
    text-align: left;
    color: #8a5225;
}
```

White box:

```
#box {
    background: url("../img/box.png") no-repeat;
    width: 163px;
    height: 41px;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
}
```

Hope you give me some solutions for that. I've been trying using the `z-index` but it doesn't bring any results...

Comment: Can you setup a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: The orange background is `back.png` that is attached to the `body`? If so, that's not gonna work. You'll have to apply that to an element other than body to get something underneath it.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5bsty/2/ , I want the `second div` to be UNDER the orange background but as the same it can be below the `third div`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this based on your current html structure. Z-index only works for positioned elements. ie `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`. You won't be able to apply these to the body element. You can try, but I tried and it didn't work. Instead put the orange background into another div and draw the lower one up under it.

http://jsfiddle.net/5bsty/

```
<div class="one">First div</div>
<div class="two">Second div</div>​

div.one {
    background: #c74d12;
    z-index: 3;
    position: relative;
}

div.two {
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
    background: white;
}
```

Comment: The background is for the whole page, so your html structure given in a fiddle is wrong, my structure is looking like that at the moment: http://jsfiddle.net/5bsty/2/ , but still I want the `second div` to be placed under the `first div` but not under the `third div`.

Comment: @Cyclone - I guess I wasn't clear in my answer. You can't do this. How can I child be underneath its parent?

Comment: +1. Thanks, but isnt there any solutions for that? I just want the white box to be slided down on mouse over from over the orange background...

Comment: Sorry, can't do that. You can't place a child behind its parent. Semantically it doesn't make any sense. Why not just change your html structure? The closest you can come is a virtual background. You absolutely position a div and then anchor with top, left, bottom, right values of zero. Basically the same as my first answer though. http://jsfiddle.net/5bsty/4/

Answer (score 0):

use  a [z-index](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/z-index) and you should be done.. give the orange background a higher z-index

Answer (score 0):

I think you look like this

You take two div and parent div define position relative and child div define absolute properties and z-index is compulsory .

**css**

```
div.one {
    background: #c74d12;
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}

div.two {
    position: absolute;
    top:11px;
    background: green;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:1;
}
​
```

**Html**

```
<div class="one">First div</div>
<div class="two">Second div</div>​
```

Check to live demo http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/5bsty/3/

Answer (score -2):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_style_zindex

Reffer this..:( ?

Comment: Friend is it that much complex to use a z-index : Hope its a better solution; Dont write code in verbose manner.

Comment: Hi query, when posting answers it is preferred not to only link out to third party source, but to provide some explanation. Also, a bunch of people on SO hate `w3schools` and downvote once they see a link from there. Annoying yes. Just a tip to avoid downvotes!