# Hiding an image behind a div [ z-index ]

Tags: html, css

I want to hide two images (partially) behind my center/main div ,just like it is shown on the picture i included [the images are blue and the center div is brown,the darker blue color is the part of the image that is supposed to be hiden behind the div].The two images are included in the HTML (as  tags).They have to be (as they currently are) part of the HTML and not "injected" via CSS.
The positining of the images isn't a problem,but the "overlaping/hiding" is.I have tried so many times via z-index but to no avail.

Can anyone help ?

link to picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCKdt.jpg

Comment: What the actual problem? Is it that z-index isn't changing the order of the elements? If so, you need to add a position attribute to them in css like: `position:relative;`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML/CSS, it's going to be harder to diagnose the problem, but it sounds like you're confusing body elements with positioned elements. Z-index won't work for body elements, so you should try to place the blue images into a div and pull that div behind your brown div.

You can find more info and a jsfiddle example at this older post: [Hiding a image under the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967929/hiding-a-image-under-the-div)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to partially hide them behind the main div, you can either set the parent container (your body tag, if nothing else contains the main div) and add your images in css using `background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.png);` and then `background-position: left center, right center;`. You can also use pixels or percentage to determine the positioning of the horizontal and vertical, respectively. That way, you don't have to bother with the z-index.

However, neither this, nor z-index will solve your other problem of having the images partially visible. For this, you can set the colour and opacity of your main div's background with `background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`, where the first three zeros can be any number from 0 to 255 which represents red, green, and blue, and the fourth zero represents any number from 0 to 1 (as decimals) which determines opacity. The lower the number, the more transparent the background is. The more transparent it is, the more you can see the images behind it.

Alternatively, you can use `opacity: 0;` in the same way as above